# Time management / personal planning service

Tags: android, web-apps, time-management

Please recommend a good time management (personal planning, todo list, GTD) service.

- It should be accessible from different platforms (at least Linux and Android), nevermind as responsive webapp like any Stack Exchange site or a set of native apps.
- I want to organize tasks using tags or categories.
- It should support configurable task deadlines and gentle reminders.

Comment: A very simple application (which doesn't meet all your requirements) is GeeTeeDee. Another popular one (im not sure if it fits your requirements of not, as i don't use it), is wunderlist

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use [Trello](https://trello.com/) exactly for the same reasons. Why I think it is a great application?

- You can create different tasklists and include tasks with deadlines and notifications
- You can add other users to the same board
- You have access from the website AND from an Android application
- The interface is really easy and user-friendly
- You can attach files on your tasks
- You have full control over who sees your boards. Plus all data is sent over a SSL/HTTPS connection, the same technology used by banks.
- It's free

Here is a screenshot from the interface:

[image: Click for full screen mode]

Answer (score 6):

All your requirements can be easily fulfilled with a GMail account and the [GTasks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dayup.gtask&hl=en) Android application.

The `TaskList` can be accessed using any browser on *desktop computers*, by logging into your GMail account, and GTasks which is, in fact, a container for Gmail tasklist, can be used from *mobile devices*.

Here's the [The Complete Guide to Google Tasks and How to Use it Effectively for Better Productivity](http://www.guidingtech.com/8535/google-tasks-guide-better-productivity/)

Some reasons for using this solution:

- it has a simple interface but completely functional;
- using the `Google Tasks API` you can handle the tasklist through your own fancy web application or to integrate it with other Google applications like `Docs`, `Spreadsheets` and `Draw`, to generate great reports! However, there is a limit for the API free using: you can do only 5,000 queries per day, from your built application.

Comment: Or alternatively for Android: [Tasks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.teamtasks.tasks.paid&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Nozbe](http://nozbe.com/apps/). It is designed for GDT workflow. It has free as well as the paid version. In free version, you can have up to 5 projects and unlimited tasks.
It supports tags, categories.
The apps support many OSes including iOS, and Android. It can work with GMail calendar and Evernote.

It has helped me to get many things done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use doitim.com , GTD service ,that is very professional.

It Support for Android,PC,Mac,IOS.

[image]

Comment: only supports trivial repeat schedules